# Scheduled Reminders Repeat Option Not Saving For Set Date Emails

Tags: wordpress, email, scheduled-reminders

I have two quarterly reminders that are not saving. I am running Civi 4.7.16 on Wordpress 4.7.3.

When I go to **Administer > Communications > Scheduled Reminders** I see my list of reminders. There are two that need to repeat quarterly. When I click **edit** then check the **Repeat "enable repetition"** box, setup my frequency and hit save. The form closes and acts like it has saved all of my options, but the Schedule Reminders shows "No" under **Repeat**. I can force it in the database, but the second I use civi to edit, the option goes back to "No"

Any ideas?

Comment: Upon further investigation, I noticed I was able to repeat the emails that used a trigger for the when statement. Those emails that used a set date were unable to repeat.

Comment: So if I say 3 weeks after Member Join Date - Good

But if I say starting 4/1/17 and repeating every 3 months we have a problem.